# GIT - Ignore commited files on deploy

Tags: git, deployment, version-control

I want to keep expanded javascript files in my repos to create a history of modifications, but  deploying just minified files (ended with .min.js). Theres a way to ignore everything that ends with .src.js just when deploying, keeping these files commited?

My post-receive:

```
#!/bin/sh
GIT_WORK_TREE=/var/www/html/mywebsite/ git checkout -f
```

In case git has no way to do that, I thought about adding some rm command into post-receive to delete files after "git checkout -f". Something like that

```
GIT_WORK_TREE blah blah blah ... git checkout -f && find /var/www/html/mywebsite/assets/js/ -type f -name "*.src.js" -exec rm -f {} \;
```

Comment: I could be wrong, but git probably isn't the best tool for deployment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I typically use rsync for things like this so that the .git directory isn't included in what gets deployed.  You can use --exclude=PATTERN to ignore the .src.js files.

rsync --delete -l -r --exclude=".git" --exclude="*.min.js" --exclude="tmp" sourceDir destDir

sourceDir or destDir can be ssh hosts as well.  I would suggest putting this in a script that you run manually instead of a git hook so you can control when changes go live.  (I typically run scripts like this with Jenkins.)

Comment: Thanks, but can you give a step by step? or maybe a link with some documenation about it. I'm a little confused.